# image upload with Magento Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: php, load-balancing, magento-1.9, cdn

My Magento store is configured with Elastic Load Balancer but when i try to upload product images from the backend sometimes it fails.

I have IP

```
192.168.2.1 - A
192.168.2.2 - B
```

My problem is there are times that images are uploaded to server B and magento fails to locate the images.

My Site is equiped with:

-Elastic Load Balancer

-CDN

-AWS

please help its been two months since i started to face this problem. I new to server staff and only follow tutorials online.

Comment: Why not use CloudFront and S3 for storing the images instead? You're already using AWS and ELB so it fits perfectly. This way, you don't have to worry about where the images are stored because S3 will provide the bucket and CloudFront will resolve the URL requests for your images without the need to identify a system where they're stored.

Comment: ok i'll note that. thankyou for fast reply.